# OSX plist editing causes app crash

Tags: osx

Does anyone have any idea why Finder (or iBooks or Mail, or Preview BUT NOT Terminal) crashes after adding the following key:value to its plist:

```
LSUIPresentationMode -int 4
```

(puts the Finder's menu bar into hide/show mode, just like the dock)

Used to work fine prior to Mavericks. And it's driving me absolutely bonkers as the annoying system menu bar is burning a ghost image into the laptop's display.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread which sounds like your issue. It's titled: [Finde Info.plist](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23953257#23953257).

*excerpt*

> In 10.8 and later, the CFPreferences agent process (cfprefsd) will cache information from these files and asynchronously write to them. This means that directly modifying plist files is unlikely to have the expected results (new settings will not necessarily be read, and may even be overwritten). You should use the NSUserDefaults or CFPreferences APIs, or the defaults(1) command, to interact with the preferences system.

***Source:** [Release Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreFoundationOlderNotes/)*

That thread also pointed to this article, titled: [How to manually edit defaults plist files in Mavericks](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57613818-263/how-to-manually-edit-defaults-plist-files-in-mavericks/).

Comment: @sim:  thanks. i read that a while back and it didn't work. tried everything to no avail. what's frustrating is that, for ex, using PlistEdit Pro works for Terminal and Firefox, but Finder, Mail, and iBooks just crash on relaunch.

if this were affecting some new Mavericks system wide app management process, then why do i get inconsistent results?  it just doesn't make any sense.

has anyone tried to modify the Finder's plist file to show/hide the system menu bar in Mavericks?  it'd be interesting to hear if people get the same result.